# accept only alphabets and numbers in textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have code where it accepts alphabets, numbers, and spaces but I want to convert it to where it only accepts alphabets (a-z, A-Z) and numbers (0-9) [So basically getting rid of accepting spaces]. Its driving me crazy and I can't figure it out. And please I want to avoid charCode as much as possible!

```
function check_username() {

        //username the user inputted
        var text_input = $('#text').val();
        if (text_input != "") {
            if (text_input.search(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/) === -1 && text_input[0] != ' ' &&
                    text_input[text_input.length - 1] != ' ' && text_input.length <= 15) {
                alert("Valid");
            }
            else if (text_input.search(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/)) {
                alert("NOT Valid");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.match` and a regular expression `/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/` Here is a example code:

```js
function alphanumeric(inputtxt) {
  var letterNumber = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
  if (inputtxt.match(letterNumber)) {
    console.log('true');
  } else {
    console.log('false');
  }
}

alphanumeric('Test Test5'); //False
alphanumeric('TestTest5'); //True
```